# Yarn Error: "The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received type boolean (true)"

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering an error while trying to use the yarn -v command in my terminal. The error message I'm seeing is:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received type boolean (true)
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
at resolve (node:path:167:9)
at loadRcFile (C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:57002:58)
at C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:56966:14
at C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:97395:14
at Array.map ()
at parseRcPaths (C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:97393:78)
at Object.findRc (C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:97407:10)
at getRcConfigForCwd (C:\Users\86182\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:56965:74)
I'm using the latest version of Yarn on a Windows machine. This error seems to be occurring internally within Yarn when it tries to load configuration files. I haven't executed any specific commands yet; this error appears when I simply run yarn -v.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it? Are there any steps I can take to troubleshoot or work around this issue? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I tried several total yarn commands and re-downloaded yarn and node still could not recover. I hope my yarn can output normally.
Remember to adjust the details in the question according to your actual situation and any additional information you may want to provide. Providing relevant tags and a clear, concise description of the problem will increase the chances of getting helpful responses from the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sometimes when it comes to config files yarn can be funny, depending on the project you are working on, especially if it's an ORM or migrations related tasks, check the docs to resolve.